# What could be reason of select2 element shrinks the width?

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

What could be a reason of this ? One element of select2 is displaying normally and the other one not ? I tried to change the structure of the html and also there are not any other styles that might override it. It seems the plugin is giving the broken select "as on the picture" dynamic width. Strange but thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's most likely just a bug with this border style. Try a different one.

Comment: Yeah but there is a question why is this working on 5 other select elements but this no 

Comment: https://codepen.io/cool-internet-guy/pen/JjGZGNw

Comment: Your code pen shows that width is calculated dynamically. Most likely by longest option value, but since you add fancy paddings, JS does not knows about it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add width options `$("#company-filter").select2({ dropdownAutoWidth : true, width : '<value>'});` instead of `$("#company-filter").select2();` and add some padding-right for dropdown button, so

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 50px;
}
```